# How can I create a python dictionary that gets its values and keys from the user through tkinter text boxes?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I really don't know where to start here. I can easily append the dictionary to accept one new variable, but ".append()" only allows for one argument so I am not sure how to include a key which is another variable into the same entry.

Comment: `append()` are for lists not dictionaries ?

Comment: @sku1031 if my answer replies to your question, you can close the question. Otherwise I will be glad to help you further

Answer (score 2):

In python you can add keys and values to a dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {} # create an empty dictionary
dict["key1"]  = "value1" # string to a key
dict["key2"]  = 0 # number to a key
dict["key3"]  = ["value1", "value2"] # array to a key
dict["key4"]  = {"key4a": "value4a"} # dictionary to a key
```

In your specific case you can:

• set an empty dictionary as a class attribute in your init

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self):
       self.dict = {}
       # the rest of your application
```

• create a method to add keys and values to this dict

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self):
       self.dict = {}
       # the rest of your application

   def append_to_dict(key, value):
       self.dict[key] = value
```

Then you can trigger this method in your application and pass to it the elements you want add as keys and values.